# Adding a Facebook like button to our App

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my app I am allowing users to post to Facebook via the iOS API as follows:

```
SLComposeViewController * controllerSLC = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
```

I would like to add a Facebook 'Like' button for users who want to like our App.  I have a couple questions:

1) Can a Facebook Like be accomplished using the Native iOS SDK?  I could not find any reference so my assumption is no, but I was hoping for some clarification.

2) If I want a user to like our app on our Facebook home page, I believe the user has to be logged in to their account.  SO, if the user is signed into Facebook on their device can I integrate the Facebook API's to that so the user does not have to log in again?  I cannot find any solid iOS example of adding a like button to my app.

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a native like button under testing and you can find the documentation about it at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/like-button . But be aware that only people will have a role on the app will see it so you can't currently use it.

If you are showing a webview the user will not be logged in in that webview even if they are logged in in the Facebook app. Same thing with redirecting to the browser. If the user is logged in in the Facebook app doesn't mean they will be logged in in the browser.

Comment: I did see that native button that is under testing, but as you can guess, it does not work for me if I cannot publish it to the App store yet.  Do I need to put the like button in a web view?  Can I not use the Facebook API call FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath?